# How to use preempt for seize blocks

Tags: anylogic

I am currently building a model on a manufacturing process line. The intention is to create a model with multiple machines and operators. An operator is seized at multiple points for performing various taskings. However, I require operators to follow a certain work schedule and go for breaks at staggered timings. As such, I have created the schedule within each agent to customise their break times.

The problem that I am faced with is I need the operator to suspend his/her current tasking whenever its time for break. Hence, I have been exploring the preempt feature within the seize block, but have failed to get what I require.

I'll illustrate an example below. Assuming that the operator is performing the current task of "receiveLot_V", while at this task, it is time for break. Upon break time, the schedule triggers to enter the flowchart to seize the current operator for break (I need to capture the duration where each operator is at break and at the same time not allow the operator at break to be available in the resource pool to be seized elsewhere).

I have allowed the seize block for break to have a higher task priority, however the operator just stays at the current position and does not seem to proceed with the process flow for break after he/she is being seized.

In addition, for certain taskings I am sending my operator to a particular node upon seizing to perform a tasking. While the operator is moving and the breaktime hits, I face an error as shown in the last image. root.pop_DirectOperators[0].enter refers to the process flow within the operator to be seized for break, and root.pop_Equipments[0].seizeDO.sendTo refers to the process where the operator is being sent to a particular node to perform his/her tasks.

How can I resolve this issue? Am I understanding the preempt feature wrongly? I've tried multiple combinations of settings with the preempt but none of them seems to work for my case.

[image: Agent current task]

[image: Operator break time]

[image: Settings of operator at current task]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Hi, this is a bit too long for a good question, but good effort :) . Can you try to shorten it so one can "digest" it within 1 min max? Create the smallest possible model that still creates the error and share details on that only, makes our lives much easier. See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow for improving your questions

Comment: typically, this type of error occurs when you manually remove an agent from a process block and enter it elsewhere, while it cannot, actually, be removed. Trace back your changes to when the error did not occur and that should help you forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like  you're trying to use a separate process to represent the breaks, which is one (uncommon) alternative (see below). The error suggests you are sending the *resource agent* into that process instead of a dummy agent which represents the 'break request' (and which will then seize the appropriate resource agent to take its break).

The typical ways of modelling pre-empting breaks are:

- Set up breaks specified by the Resource Pool properties (ensuring they have a higher priority than that for agents which seize those resources). This works fine if your breaks have a fixed schedule of occurrence. Then have pre-emption occur in all Service/Seize blocks that you want to be affected by break pre-emption.
- As above but use a Downtime block to specify the pattern of breaks. Gives a bit more flexibility in how breaks are specified but still only within the limits of what a Downtime block can specify.
- For a completely 'custom' situation (where, for example, breaks might need to be determined dynamically for indivividual resource units in some way), use a separate process flow to 'cause' the breaks: inject agents representing the break request (so e.g., of custom type `BreakRequest`) into the process which seize the appropriate resource from the appropriate pool (where this injection could be driven from behaviour within the individual resource unit agents themselves), and model the ensuing break in whatever way is needed (e.g., just a plain Delay or something more complex that determines when their break will end). You need to ensure that the break request agent has a higher priority than other tasks (i.e., other agents flowing into other Service/Seize blocks) and is set to pre-empt.

The important things to understand are:

- You specify "Task may preempt" on the blocks *where the tasks that will pre-empt others (if higher priority) occur* (i.e., you specify this on the Service/Seize blocks of the 'pre-empters').
- You specify "Task preemption policy" on the blocks *where the tasks that will be pre-empted occur* (i.e., you specify this on the Service/Seize blocks for the 'pre-empted'). And then you have the specified options in terms of what to do with the task (agent) that has been 'kicked out'. If you specify "No preemption" then the pre-emption won't happen even if the 'source' task is set to pre-empt and has a higher priority.
- Priorities are 'global' (e.g., if you say in a special breaks process flow Seize block that the incoming agent has priority 100, then the seize request that it then sends to the relevant resource pool will be compared against the priorities of all other tasks those resource agents are doing or have been asked to do, which are determined from whatever Seize/Service block they arrived in originally).

Your screenshots suggest you haven't set up the pre-emption block options on the correct blocks (as well as possibly/probably sending the wrong agent into your special breaks flow); see info above.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the advice provided. I'm still rather confused, as I thought that my approach is similar to the 'custom' situation you have mentioned? In addition, if I were to inject the agent to a separate process flow, will another available agent be seized to perform the current task? (aka takeover the operator who went for break?) Lastly, is there any existing example model that provides good insight on how operator schedules, breaks etc are utilised? I've looked through quite a handful of models, but none of them builds on scheduling extensively. Thank you once again!

Comment: Your approach is (from what I can see) similar to the 'custom approach' but it looks like you are sending the resource agent itself into the process, not a dummy agent representing a break request for it (where that dummy agent would, say, contain a parameter which specifies which resource unit agent it is for, so that you can use "Resource choice condition" in the Seize/Service block to seize exactly that unit).

Comment: I got mixed up with which blocks require which settings; see edited answer. (You specify "Task may preempt" on the 'pre-empters' block(s) and "Task preemption policy" on the 'pre-empted' block(s).

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood what I've done wrongly already. Greatly appreciate your guidance!